# About request.setTesting(true) code line

Tags: android, admob

I want to include **admob** in my android PhoneGap app.

To include admob, I referred link https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob

My question is about below code line.

```
request.setTesting(true);
```

Must I remove that code line when app on market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this in the link provided by you

**Step 6) Disable Testing Mode**

Be **sure to disable testing mode before deploying to Google Play by changing the value to false**, **commenting out or deleting the following line** from your MainActivity.java

```
request.setTesting(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It mean that I have to remove that code when app on market? Sorry! I don't know english well so can not understand 'step 6' sentence.

Comment: Yes you have to remove that line.

Answer (score 4):

In admob admin interface there is checkbox to treat testmode requests as regular requests.